# WP7 Saving data in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I save data in isolated storage, but when I restart my Phone I can not read this data from there. Isolated storage is empty. Why?

If I don't switch off phone all work Ok

This is my code:

```
 using (Stream file = IsolatedStorageHelper.OpenFile(USER_ACCOUNT_FILE, fileMode.Create))
        {
            if (null != file)
            {
                try
                {
                    XDocument xml = new XDocument();
                    XElement root = new XElement("userAccount");

                    root.Add(new XAttribute("FirstName", this._firstName));
                    root.Add(new XAttribute("LastName", this._lastName));
                    root.Add(new XAttribute("ID", this._id));
                    root.Add(new XAttribute("Sex", this._sex));

                    xml.Add(root);

                    // save xml data
                    xml.Save(file);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Function what create file in Issolated Storage

```
static public IsolatedStorageFileStream OpenFile(string aFilename, FileMode mode)
            {
                IsolatedStorageFileStream res = null;

                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {

                    try
                    {
                        res = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(aFilename, mode, FileAccess.ReadWrite, isoStore);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        if ((null != (exc as IsolatedStorageException)) &&
                            (FileMode.Open != mode) &&
                            (true == createPathOnIsolatedStorage(isoStore,aFilename)) )
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                res = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(aFilename, mode, isoStore);
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return res;
            }
```

Comment: Do you use an actual device or you're talking about the emulator ?

Comment: What happens when your app starts up?  Is OpenFile() called?  The FileMode that you should be using for OpenFile should probably be FileMode.OpenOrCreate, not FileMode.Open.  FileMode.Open will always recreate the file and overwrite any data you had before.

Comment: I tested on the emulator.  Already I  am run app on  the phone, everything become to work. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about running this on the emulator, this is **normal behavior**. The emulator does not preserve isolated storage by default.

A physical device will always keep the data in the storage unless it is explicitly reset, the application was uninstalled or the content was deleted by the user through one of the means provided by your application.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I tested the application on the emulator, when I tested it on the phone all started working well